# instruct AS3 gotoAndPlay

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an AS3 movie clip that I want to return to first frame whenever it reaches the last frame.

The movieclip instance name is **sym2**.

I tried -

**_root.sym2.gotoAndPlay(1);**
and
**sym2.gotoAndPlay(1);**

but it doesn't work.

How can I instruct the movie clip to restart playing from first frame ?

regards

Comment: The first frame is 0, and not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good way of writing it without writing inside frames:

```
var backToStart:Function = new Function(){
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
yourMovieClip.addFrameScript(yourMovieClip.totalFrames, backToStart);
//place this in the constructor
```